# On linux can I copy a file using a headphone jack, audio cable, and microphone jack

Tags: audio, file-transfer

I would like to transfer a file (i.e., lossless transfer) from a Linux computer to another computer using only the headphone output. I would use an audio cable and plug into to the receiving computer's microphone input. Is this possible? How do I set it up?

To be clear: I have no USB, Ethernet, etc available.  Headphone jack is it.  So obviously I need a software modem.  Does one exist?

Comment: In theory this could be done, however I doubt you will find the needed drivers already written.

Comment: Given that people have built hacks that send TCP/IP data over commodity LEDs, speakers, and IDE cables, this is most certainly possible. Modern audio cards also have an order of magnitude more bandwidth than the best analogue modems.

Comment: Honest question here: how the file got in there in the first place?

Comment: More important: how would you install a software modem on the destination machine if it doesn't have any traditional data inputs?

Comment: Is it 1st April already?

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely possible though a lot slower than you may be used to.

Back in the day, you could save data and software to audio cassettes using a tape recorder. (That was how it was done before floppy disks were cheap enough for the general public.) There was no way to do bidirectional communication during that so they used various error correction techniques to help ensure the data was load-able despite the variable, noisy environment that was audio recording before digital audio was a thing.

A variation on this would be to "save" the data as audio, just as one might save to a cassette recorder. (Rather than being connected to a cassette recorder, you'd connect to the "line in" on another computer.) The other computer would be setup to "load" the data from that "line in" connection.

I'm not sure if such facilities are readily available on today's Linux. But there are various sound and error correction libraries around and the technologies are simple enough that a bit of research and elbow grease should eventually get you what you want.

Looking around it seems there is still some interest in this kind of technology. [This page](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/) describes `minimodem` (and how to get it), a piece of Linux software that looks like it does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"Back in the day, you could save data and software to audio cassettes using a tape recorder"* -- A bit misleading, as that did require ***modulator*** hardware interface to convert the digital data stream to an analog audio signal.  Your "variation" on saving the data as audio won't work because you misunderstand the modulation required.   However `minimodem` does seem like a solution (if it can be installed), although the source file may have to be processed with a modem protocol before handing over to `minimodem`, and then processed in reverse on the receiving end.

Comment: @sawdust Saving data "as" anything implies that there is some kind of translation going on. In the cases I mentioned, yes, it was done in hardware and, yes, a modulator was part of that hardware. Given the memory and processing power we have these days, it seems such things can be done in software now, possibly in real-time. `minimodem` doesn't have to be used. OP already stated that he doesn't have network so it's not like he can download anything. Even so, it seems it'd still be possible to write a shell script that can encode data into a usable audio stream or decode a recorded stream.

Answer (score 3):

Totally doable on a modern Linux system. As mentioned above [Minimodem](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/) is what you want. You'll get at least 2400bps (2.4kbps), maybe more, over a closed loop. If it is a quiet room you can do 100bps with just a speaker, microphone, and sound waves. Youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwuyMJfyNmY). You'll need to familiarize yourself with c-kermit for the actual file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the constraints of your question, I think a traditional modem would actually be overkill. You don't *need* a TCP connection to do a file transfer over an audio connection, and you might be better off without all the networking overhead.

So let's break down this question. On one computer, you have an arbitrary data file, and you want to encode it in such a way that it can be played as audio, then decoded on a different machine.

The playback and record part should be pretty easy -- once you have a generated audio file, a program like Audacity could be used to record this from the audio input on the other machine. So the hard part is encoding and decoding the audio stream.

Why not use [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code)? You would be able to use a hexadecimal representation of your data, and tools exist both for programmatic [encoding](http://www.robertecker.com/hp/research/morse-generator.php?lang=en) and [decoding](http://morsecode.scphillips.com/labs/decoder/#) from audio.

Of course, the mention of any extra tool required for decoding raises the question: how would you get this tool on your destination machine in the first place? (This would be true for a software modem as well.) If you're going to be typing in a program on the destination machine to do the decoding for you, well, an open source javascript library isn't a completely terrible idea.

You can use a simple checksum hash to verify accuracy after encoding, transmission, and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Could binary data be converted to audio and back again? [Of course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem). And I'm sure there are [software](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/) solutions for this, although I highly doubt they'd be close to lossless and I've never tried them.

Would I recommend it? Not at all. Bear in mind, using the output from one machine to the input of another means there is no way the receiving machine could re-request any data it didn't get, although you could engineer a way to parity check what you've received. Add to this that normal consumer level headphone and microphone chipsets/codecs are unlikely to be as pitch accurate as you'd need for anything close to a lossless connection. They may also have some behind the scene equalizer settings or gain, as such you may have to be lucky to transfer data at all.

You won't get a verifiable lossless data transfer you could in any way rely upon. But you could *potentially* transfer data.

Comment: You can most certainly get verifiable lossless data.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm struggling to understand how with a one-way communication you could achieve this. With hindsight (will amend my answer) you could provide parity to check against, which could confirm if you've lost data, but I can't figure how you'd re-request any failed data without being able to send a response to the server (I was thinking it'd be comparable to a UDP connection). Of course you could continually send the same redundant data, but that still wouldn't guarantee a perfect transfer, nor would it be a very efficient practice?

Comment: The same way you can verify the losslessness of a ZIP file someone has emailed you.

Comment: you just have to have software that breaks your data up into packets and computes a checksum on the packets. then if the checksum for a packet is bad, you send down a retransmission request or simply don't ack the packet however your lossless protocol is set up to work. Even a protocol written on top of UDP can be lossless as long as the protocol you are using implements retransmissions

Comment: @SE _send down a retransmission request_ How do you achieve this with a one way communication such as this?

Comment: @Jonno, well if it is a combo port that has both a mic and an audio out, such as those used for headsets, then you just have to write out the audio port from the target device, otherwise you would have to use a separate cable that connects to the target pc's mic so it can get feedback. typically the computers that have only 1 audio jack are combo ports that can go both ways provided you have the correct cable